# Include ActiveStorage URL to image in JSON response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to simply show the URL to images which I've attached to my User model.

```
  def show
    render json: @user, include: [:images]
  end
```

The above response gives me:-

```
{
    "id": 2288,
    "name": "Joe Bloggs",
    "images": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "images",
            "record_type": "User",
            "record_id": 2288,
            "blob_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2021-04-20T13:53:16.663Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

From the Rails API docs and other stackoverflow posts, I should be using the `service_url` or `url` method like below:-

```
  def show
    render json: @user, include: [images: {methods: :service_url}]
  end
```

The above however, gives me:-

```
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "#<URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): nil>",
```

How do I achieve what I want here?

I've also used binding.pry to try and manually get the path with

```
@user.images.first.url
@user.images.first.blob
@user.images.first.blob.url
@user.images.first.blob.service_url
```

and every single one of the above gives me:-

```
NameError: uninitialized constant #<Class:0x0000ffffb02e5e18>::Analyzable
```

A bit stumped as to why this isn't easily done in Rails.

Comment: Add `delegate :service_url, to: :blob` in your Image class if you want to be able to call it on image instances. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to this was to set the host, by adding the below:-

```
include ActiveStorage::SetCurrent
```

in my controller.

Comment: Crazy it's so hard. Thanks for this. doing this adds the url to all the other info. How would you just get the url from it? Inside `images` instead of having all the other props